# regular expression: matching certain format but excluding specific value

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to verify that a value is a mobile phone number and at the same time, does not match one specific mobile phone number.

For example, the value should be 7 or 8 numbers in length but should not be 01010101.

- 12346789 (0)
- 1234323 (0)
- 01010101 (x)
- 0101010 (0)

Some kind of AND operator is required, but I can't seem to figure out appropriate form.

Below is a failed approach.

```
/^(?=\d{7,8}))(?!(01010101))$/
```

Edit: This regex is going to be used in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your approach is failing is that you are trying to match:
7-8 digits followed by not 01010101

If you want to have it the regex in that particular order you need to use negative lookbehind

```
^(\d{7,8})(?<!(01010101))$
```

Furthermore (this might be intetional, but) you are using both lookahead and negative lookahead which means you wont **capture** anything - just match.
The expression above will capture the numbers in the first capturing group ($1).

---

JavaScript does not support negative lookbehind according to http://regexr.com/
You could use the equivalent expression:

```
^(?!(01010101))(\d{7,8})$
```

Alternatively remove ^ and $ if you are using http://regexr.com/ and want to match multiple rows

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't know that regex expressions are different depending on language. I've got an error that lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript from http://regexr.com/.

Comment: You could also do ^(?!(01010101))(\d{7,8})$

Answer (score 1):

Your regex never going to match any string until moving the end anchor(`$`) to the assertion parentheses. The below regex would be simple assert the position and it doesn't capture any value.

```
/^(?=\d{7,8}$)(?!01010101$)/
```

---

Use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid that particular pattern.

```
/^(?!01010101$)\d{7,8}$/
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/az2AGK/1)

Where `\d{7,8}` would match any number combination of length `7` or `8` and for avoiding `01010101` combination use [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)(`(?!01010101$)`) which fail to match from the beginning itself.

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned above in comments, I'm sorry that I didn't explain that I'm going to use this regex in Javascript. Do you think there's another way?

Comment: @HeeKyungYoon :  what you mean by another way ?

Comment: @HeeKyungYoon :  JS  supports look ahead assertion and not supported look behind...

Comment: When I tested `/^(?!01010101$)\d{7,8}$/` in https://regex101.com/ with Javascript flavor mode, it didn't work. But @Tim said it works in Javascript too!

Comment: @HeeKyungYoon :  yes it will work in JS - https://regex101.com/r/aqg3Nd/1

Answer (score 0):

This regex worked for me when testing:

```
^((?!01010101$)\d{7,8})$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

**Explanation:** This regex checks that the string contains either 7 or 8 digits, but at each point of the match, it asserts that the string does not contain `01010101`, which is the number you *don't* want to match.

Note that using a negative lookahead appears to be completely acceptable in Javascript.  For example, the following match would return true:

```
/^((?!01010101$)\d{7,8})$/.test('1234567');
```

while the following would return false:

```
/^((?!01010101$)\d{7,8})$/.test('01010101');
```

Comment: Thanks for your demo. I'm sorry to mention that I'm going to use this regex in Javascript. When I changed mode to Javascript, it is no longer valid. Do you think there's another way?

Comment: @HeeKyungYoon There is nothing wrong with using a negative lookahead in JavaScript, q.v. my updated answer.